# What are the new policies of worldbuilding?

Tags: support

Someone told me that there are new policies of WB,I missed that,Please someone share me a link to the new policies so i wont break the rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably referring to [this comment](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121363/how-can-i-make-reverse-war-rape-more-demoralizing#comment374451_121363), which in turn is referring to the new network wide [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct):

> Keeping in mind the new "be ludicrously nice to everyone" policy I can't tell you how precisely how disgusted I am with a your question. Suffice to say I don't regard rape of any kind as reasonable topics for Worldbuilding.

The new *Code of Conduct* is the same as the old *Be nice.* - just with more explanation for people who didn't understand *Be nice.*

The user was just trying to tell you how appalling they find your question.